# ggplot: Order stacked barplots by variable proportion

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am creating a plot with 3 variables as below. Is there a way to arrange the plot in a descending order such that the bar with the highest proportion of variable "c" comes first in the plot. Using this example last bar should come in first then middle one and then the first bar in the last.

```
long<- data.frame(
      Name = c("abc","abc","abc","gif","gif","gif","xyz","xyz","xyz"),
      variable = c("a","b","c","a","b","c","c","b","a"),
      value = c(4,6,NA,2,8,1,6,NA,NA))
    
    
long_totals <- long %>%
      group_by(Name) %>%
      summarise(Total = sum(value, na.rm = T))
    
    p <- ggplot()+
      geom_bar(data = long,
               aes(x = Name, 
                   y = value,
                   fill=variable),
               stat="summary", 
               position = "fill") +
      geom_text(data = long_totals,
                aes(y = 100,
                    x = Name,
                    label = Total),
                size = 7,
                position = position_fill(vjust = 1.02)) +
      scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format()) +
      ylab("Total_num") +
      ggtitle("Totalnum") +
      theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 20, hjust = 0.5)) +
      theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 75, vjust = 0.95, hjust=1))
```

The following code does arrange the bars by count of "c" but not by proportion. How can I arrange by proportion?

```
    p<-long %>%
mutate(variable = fct_relevel(variable, 
                                    c("c", "b", "a"))) %>%
      
      arrange(variable) %>%        
      mutate(Name = fct_inorder(Name))  
      
      p %>% 
      ggplot() +
      aes(x = Name,
          y = value,
          fill = variable) +
      geom_bar(position = "fill",
               stat = "summary") +
```

Comment: Just a general comment: you would perhaps be better off using `geom_col()` here instead of geom_bar().

Answer (score 2):

We could use `fct_rev` from `forcats` package, it is in `tidyverse`:

```
p <- ggplot()+
  geom_bar(data = long,
           aes(x = fct_rev(Name), 
               y = value,
               fill=variable),
           stat="summary", 
           position = "fill") +
  geom_text(data = long_totals,
            aes(y = 100,
                x = Name,
                label = Total),
            size = 7,
            position = position_fill(vjust = 1.02)) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format()) +
  ylab("Total_num") +
  ggtitle("Totalnum") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 20, hjust = 0.5)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 75, vjust = 0.95, hjust=1))
```

[image]

Comment: how are we passing the information for "c" to be arranged in a desc order?

Comment: I do not want to reverse the order necessarily but want to actually arrange it by "c".

Comment: Ok i got it. Will adapt.